# IntelliJ IDEA: File Structure in Find Usages Menu is Only Visible on Mouse Hover After Installing New Theme

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

After installing 3rd part of theme [NEWUI] `Gradianto Midnight Blue`, I tried to find usages to the method and in some rows, there is no method name; it only appears if I hover the mouse over it. I tried to get back with the standard theme, invalidated cache and restarted Intellij Idea, but it remains the same. I know it should work differently because my college has no issue with showing methods, and for 2 years of using Intellij Idea, I've never seen anything like this.

It looks like this:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECgSN.png)

1. I click with the left mouse and ctrl on the join method.
2. I see
   usages but should put the cursor on the line to see the method name.
3. ???

Do you know how to fix it?

I am expecting to see method names.

Comment: Does it work fine with default theme?